# Am I really connected to multiple networks at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, android, tethering

I'm using my Droid Incredible to tether and I'm using my library's WiFi and I swear I'm streaming faster than when I'm just connected to one. Am I really connected to both networks at the same time? How is this possible? Does my phone act as its own wireless adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple network connections at the same time.  Whether Windows is actually splitting up the traffic between the two or not, is another question all together, but you can certainly be connected to multiple networks at the same time.